# Why doesn't my three.js code show the light effect?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Following the manual, I made a three.js example, but the light effect doesn't appear, why the light source doesn't appear without any error about the light source?

```
import * as THREE from "/assets/threejs/build/three.module.js"

class App {
    // 생성 초기화
    constructor(){
        const divContainer = document.querySelector("#webgl-container");
        this._divContainer = divContainer;

        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true})
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        divContainer.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        this._renderer = renderer;

        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this._scene = scene;

        this._setupCamera();
        this._setupLight();
        this._setupModel();

        window.onresize = this.resize.bind(this);
        this.resize();

        requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
    }
    
    // 카메라
    _setupCamera() {
        const width = this._divContainer.clientWidth;
        const height = this._divContainer.clientHeight;
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
            75,
            width / height,
            0.1,
            100,
        )
        camera.position.z = 2
        this._camera = camera;
    }

    // 광원
    _setupLight(){
        const color = 0xffffff;
        const intensity = 1;
        const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
        light.position.set(-1, 2, 4);
        this._scene.add(light);
    }

    // 모델
    _setupModel(){
        const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x44a88 } );
        const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        this._scene.add(cube);
        this._cube = cube;
    }
 
    // 창크기 번경
    resize(){
        const width = this._divContainer.clientWidth;
        const height = this._divContainer.clientHeight;

        this._camera.aspect = width / height;
        this._camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        this._renderer.setSize(width, height);
    }

    // 랜더링
    render(time){
        this._renderer.render(this._scene, this._camera);
        this.update(time);
        requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
    }

    // 업데이트
    update(time){
        time *= 0.001;
        this._cube.rotation.x = time;
        this._cube.rotation.y = time;
    }

}

window.onload = function(){
    new App(); 
}
```

The screenshot below is the result of my example code.
[image]

The screenshot below is the result of the manual.
[image]

I'm sorry for posting multiple questions with a low difficulty problem, but, I'm learning three.js for the first time. In vscode, there is no three.js code hint library, and it's hard. How can I express the light effect normally in my example code? Will there be? thanks for reading the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use [`MeshBasicMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshBasicMaterial), but [`MeshStandardMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial). `MeshBasicMaterial` for drawing geometries in a flat or wireframe way. `MeshStandardMaterial` is a physically based material that makes the surface interact with the light.